# MPGS Integrations CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION cURL

Tags: php, rest, curl, payment-processing, mastercard

Im trying to configure MPGS and trying to setup the callback url. it requires creating a session using REST.

the code is something like the bellow one. im not sure how is the code should be written with cURL. can anybody help

Thanks

```
POST https://cbcmpgs.gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/47/merchant/XXXXXXXXXX/session


{
"apiOperation": "CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION",
"order": {
 "currency": "LKR",
 "id": "20181003001"
},
"interaction": {
 "returnUrl": "http://www.google.lk"
}
```

Comment: Is it a must for you to use cURL? I think an Ajax request should also do the trick. Should be fairly simple with jquery. If it is okay to use Ajax I can provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = '';
$postFields = array(
    'apiOperation' => 'CREATE_CHECKOUT_SESSION',
    'order' => array(
        'currency' => '',
        'id' => ''
    ),
    'interaction' => array(
        'returnUrl' => ''
    )
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postFields));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```